# Gravity's point of application on a beam attached to a wall by a hinge and a wire

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque

For a beam attached to a wall with a hinge and its other end is supported by a
a wire that's attached to a wall:

[image]

I am wondering if the force of gravity exerted on the beam will be at the center of its length? in other words, if the length of the beam is $L$, the point where the gravity is exerted is $L/2$ from either end of the beam. If so, why is it that. If not, why not?

Comment: Why would you not think so?

Comment: @BobD I think it's because the beam is slanted as it's hung on the wall, so I become unsure (I'm aware that it must be acting at the center for a beam that lies on a level ground)

Comment: The force of gravity acts through the COM. The location of the COM of the beam does not change if the beam is slanted.